# Lazy loading navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

It seems I am unable to put a where clause on the include in my domain service - so we are doing some loops to get the data we need for some lookupGroups.

```
   var _lookupGroups = _lookupGroupRepository.All();
        var _lookupValues = _institutionLookupValueRepository.All().Where(x => x.InstitutionID == _userProfile.InstitutionID);

        int i = 0;

        foreach (var _group in _lookupGroups)
        {
            var _values = _lookupValues.Where(x => x.LookupGroupID == _group.LookupGroupID);

            foreach (var _value in _values)
            {
                _group.InstitutionLookupValues.Add(_value);

                i++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(_group.GroupName + " " + i.ToString());
        }

        return _lookupGroups;
```

The counter I put in was for some validation on what i was seeing - the first group that we iterate through is States. my counter will say 50 but my navigation property will say 100, showing one set of 50 for each Institution we have (we have 2 sets). so it is going and getting all the lookupvalues and putting them in the navigation property even though my counter says 50. also i have removed all includes in the metadata file.

To clarify: i have lookupvalues that are attached to lookupGroups. the lookup values are assigned to institutions. so if i go get the values for the lookup group of STATES i would get back 50 lookup values. the code above. when i run this line _group.InstitutionLookupValues.Add(_value); my InstitutionLookupValues = 100 (taking all lookupValues regardless of institution). but my counter shows 50. somewhere I am getting all the lookup values not sure the ones tied to a specific institution.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What is your counter? Is it a problem with the different numbers?

Comment: thanks - have updated the question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is caused by the fact you're accessing a modified closure, and, even if it isn't, you shouldn't be anyway. The line

```
var _values = _lookupValues.Where(x => x.LookupGroupID == _group.LookupGroupID);
```

probably isn't doing what you think it's doing (unless it's C#5).  The lambda is a delegate and the closure will close over the variable, not the value.  This means your code `_group.LookupGroupID` will always be the last value from the final iteration of the enumerator, so you'll only ever filter the lookup values on one `_group.LookupGroupID`.

Try changing the block to:

```
foreach (var _group in _lookupGroups)
{
  var currentGroup = _group;    
  var _values = _lookupValues.Where(x => x.LookupGroupID == currentGroup.LookupGroupID);

  foreach (var _value in _values)
  {
     currentGroup.InstitutionLookupValues.Add(_value);

     i++;
  }

  Console.WriteLine(currentGroup.GroupName + " " + i.ToString());
}
```

I'm not sure whether that's the cause of the problem, but you'll get other weird effects anyway.  By creating your own variable within the loop, you avoid closing over the  generated enumerator variable.

Take a look at Eric Lippert's articles on this: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).  It's surprising how few people are aware of this issue.

Also, it's probably a good idea to collapse the query:

```
var _lookupValues = _institutionLookupValueRepository.All().Where(x => x.InstitutionID == _userProfile.InstitutionID);
```

by using `ToList()`, or similar.  Otherwise you'll be re-evaluating this query for each loop in the `_lookupGroups` and this could be a nasty performance hit if either the query is to a database, or the loop is large.

Comment: That is a great analysis - thanks - i will try this out and report back, thank you.

Comment: Still got the same results with this code change - i see 100 states in that navigation property when its done going through the first lookupGroup.

Comment: Well, it's valid anyway ;)  Are you saying that each `_group` (which I'm presuming matches to an EF table, has an empty collection on `InstitutionLookupValues` at the start?  What results do you get for `InstitutionLookupValues` after your loop, if you don't run the `Add` method?